# ES6 - Variable being defined inside closure with a name same as a variable in parent scope yields undefined

Tags: javascript

I spent hours looking at this piece of code:

```
1:   const { services, lists } = this.props;
2: 
3:   const List = _.map(lists.list, (list) => {
4:     const services = _.filter(services.list, (service) => lists.services.indexOf(service.id) > -1);
5:     ...
120:   ...
121: });
```

At line number 4, I get an error:

> Cannot read property list of undefined

At line number 4, property list is being referenced by `services`, apparently. And, it is undefined. But, at line 1, it's defined which can be checked by logging its value.

I know the value of `services` becomes undefined in the closure because JS has its way of finding the variable declarations first and assigning undefined to them before executing the given function. My concern is that, should it be the behavior with the given piece of code considering it's being pre-compiled using Babel?

Comment: `const services` masks the "global" `services` obtained using `const { services, lists } = this.props;` - end of story, babel has nothing to do with it - if you write "bad code" a transpiler wont fix it

Comment: you can see what your code gets transpiled to, this will help to see what babel does with your code

https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=AQjGHsDsGcBdgN7GgUwE4DcCWoXQDTAA2Wc0wAvsALzCwAWpAdAA5rgvQDcwAUCMAgx4AGVLxaAfSYBbAIYsAFCTJMVsQsvEBKGgD5E_AYKhxk6bLnJSmAMyxFY6Rakw48a8ZteWUu6gbq0Ew-7sFYkAAmKAAeAPK2LhbuTFiRugYAtACM2lz8FHlAA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2016%2Ces2017%2Clatest%2Cstage-0&targets=&version=6.26.0

Comment: you can also notice the issue if you paste the code in the TypeScript playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Comment: JaromandaX Well, I already got to know that it was the issue. But, I was just concerned that Babel should have thrown a better error message like it does in browsers that support newer versions of JavaScript: ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'a' before initialization. Now, it's cleared up.

@Joey Thanks, but the issue was not so obvious even in the transpiled version.

Comment: @Slai Yes, I just figured that out. But, I was not using TypeScript before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** I realized that this was your actual question:

> My concern is that, should it be the behavior with the given piece of code considering it's being pre-compiled using Babel?

The answer is no, Babel's job is to convert code into its older equivalent, the equivalent here being a `var` statement. The `const` statement you have there is perfectly valid syntactically, but is destined to throw an error semantically (note: if you actually executed that `const` statement in an environment that supports const, it would throw an error before you even tried to access `service`'s `list` property).

---

Original answer:

If you define a variable in the same line that you use it, it will always be undefined the first time the statement tries to access it, even if there's a variable with the same name in an outer scope:

```js
const a = 2;

function f() {
    const a = a + 1;    // error
    console.log(a);    
}

f();
```

**The solution:** don't reuse variable names in inner scopes. Just come up with new names for your variables:

```
const filteredServices = _.filter(services.list, (service) => lists.services.indexOf(service.id) > -1);
```

Comment: I agree that we can always come up with new names. But, shouldn't there be a better error thrown? Atleast, in Babel? It should check if the variable being referenced in the initialization of another variable with the same name which exists in the outer scope must not allowed. I seriously spent hours on this. If I use compilers, I expect them to be good.

Comment: @RexOverflow It's not Babel's job to babysit your code. Babel's job is to transpile the statements into previous versions of JavaScript. What you had there was perfectly valid syntax, but what you were trying to do there would cause an error in any version of JavaScript. If you want a compiler to prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot, maybe try the TypeScript compiler? It would have caught this.

Comment: I agree. Let me accept your answer and keep this question intact. It may someone else. BTW, it'll throw error one line above.

Comment: In your edits, are you referring to this error? `ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'a' before initialization` Ain't it better? xD

Comment: @RexOverflow Yes, but that is a _runtime_ error. Babel doesn't run your code. It converts its syntax.